# Is 1N2 (Spadaro) in class G or D airspace?

Tags: faa-regulations, airspace

I am confused about the situation where an airport is located in class G airspace and at the same time located in class D airspace. As we can see the picture below [Spadaro (1N2)](https://www.aopa.org/destinations/airports/1N2/details) is located inside the [Francis S Gabreski (KFOK)](https://www.aopa.org/destinations/airports/KFOK/details), am I right? If so, do I need to call tower before entering class D?

[image]

Comment: You have two different questions here so I edited it to focus on the first one: what airspace is 1N2 in? I don't think we have a question on this site about the requirements for entering class D airspace (I may be wrong), but the answer is fairly well known (91.129 and AIM 3-2-5). You can always ask that as a new question if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking class D airspace generally has a radius of 4 NM. If you take a look at the TAC chart or hop on your favorite flight app you will see the field actually sits just outside the airspace.

[image]

The sectional is likely drawn this way to allow for 49N and 1N2 to both be properly depicted.

Officially the airport is closed [according to the current AF/D](http://aeronav.faa.gov/afd/19jul2018/ne_195_19JUL2018.pdf) it appears to have been shut down in [2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spadaro_Airport), so it may be listed there simply for visual reference as the physical runway seems to still exist but traffic overlap is no longer an issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering the question.